# What does "half glance" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The grin vanished from Fred's face. Harry saw George **half glance** at Fred, before smiling at Ron.

I'm not sure what "*half glance*" means exactly. I guess it just means *to take a very quick glance*. Is my understand correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have an "exact" meaning. A fleeting glance, and not an obvious one. Their eyes briefly met.